# format string template with named parameters to literal c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, string.format, stringtemplate

I have an application that creates string templates with named variables. This is done in accordance to the logging guide for [ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#log-message-template)

Now I find myself wanting to deliver these strings through the API itself as well, but this time with all the parameters filled in.

Basicly I'd want to use:

```
var template = "ID {ID} not found";
var para = new object[] {"value"};
String.Format(template, para);
```

However this gives an invalid input string.
Ofcourse I also cannot guarantee that somebody din't make a string template the 'classic' way with indexes.

```
var template2 = "ID {0} not found";
```

Is there a new way of formatting strings that I'm missing or are we supposed to work around this ?

I do not want to rework the existing code base to use numbers or use the $"...{para}" syntax. As this would lose information when it is being logged.

I'm guessing I could do a regex search and see if there's a '{0}' or a named parameter, and replace the named with indexes before formatting. But I wanted to know if there are some easier/cleaner ways of doing this.

## Update - regex solution:

Bellow is the current work-around I've made using regex

```
public static class StringUtils
    {
        public static string Format(string template, params object[] para)
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(template, @"\{@?\w+}");
            if (!match.Success) return template;

            if (int.TryParse(match.Value.Substring(1, match.Value.Length - 2), out int n))
                return string.Format(template, para);
            else
            {
                var list = new List<string>();
                var nextStartIndex = 0;
                var i = 0;
                while (match.Success)
                {
                    if (match.Index > nextStartIndex)
                        list.Add(template.Substring(nextStartIndex , match.Index - nextStartIndex) + $"{{{i}}}");
                    else
                        list.Add($"{{{i}}}");

                    nextStartIndex = match.Index + match.Value.Length;

                    match = match.NextMatch();
                    i++;
                }

                return string.Format(string.Join("",list.ToArray()), para);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you try `String.Format(template, string.Join(", ", para));`

Comment: The logging provider used by the ASP.NET Core loggin extensions uses its own formatting code. Some providers actually understand that template, eg Serilog. Some don't. What do you mean `deliver these strings through the API itself as well` though? Whose API?

Comment: I'm making an API and I want to show these messages to the user, that are otherwise just used for logging. Serilog understanding these templates is basicly why I don't want to just rework the code-base to use indexes. I'm using the same string templates and their params for both logging and returning to the user in certain cases.

Comment: The approach you're suggesting can lead to runtime errors. If you use "normal" string interpolation then you'll get a compiler error if you have the wrong number of arguments, which is good. If you just have an `object[]` then it will compile, but at runtime you could have the wrong number of type of arguments, which is bad. Anything that gets you a compiler error instead of a runtime error is better.

Comment: You've added the regex example. Somewhere upstream from where you call this function, you're going to need some code that selects the template. And if your argument is a class with properties, you'll have to convert those properties into a list of parameters (objects.) I'd look for a solution at the point where you're doing that work. Somewhere you've got some arguments you want to format and a decision that tells you what template you need. What does that look like? I'd move it there and avoid a solution that hopes your format string will match your arguments and breaks when it doesn't match.

Comment: It might be useful to reference Serilog's own code for this. I dug it up quick, but I think this is the right thing: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Formatting/Display/MessageTemplateTextFormatter.cs. In short, there's nothing in C# directly to help you with this.